# Memory-access caveat for multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool, or can be fixed using variable arguments?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, pool, argv

I have the following code which works well:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests


# Retrieve data using get request
def get_docs():
    try:
        docs = requests.get(url).json()['data']
        return docs
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")

# Index dictionary for each attribute
def get_attributes(doc):
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = doc["id"], doc["created_utc"], doc["title"], doc["subreddit"]
    return (x1, x2, x3, x4)

# Map each document to the attribute function
def get_data(docs):
    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(get_attributes, docs)
        return results


docs = get_docs()
data = get_data(docs)

print(data)
```

But what I really want to do is have get_attributes() look like this:

```
def get_attributes(doc):
    """
    Using either Pool or ThreadPool
    """
    with Pool(4) as p:
        results = p.map(some_function(doc), ["id", "created_utc", "title", "subreddit"])
        return results


# Where the get_attributes function iteratively maps attributes to one document:
def some_function(doc, arg):
    return doc[arg]


# And then ultimately this should work
def get_data(docs):
    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(get_attributes, docs)
        return results
```

I get different Errors depending on whether Pool or ThreadPool is used for get_attributes, making me thing it has to do with how memory is stored/accessed with `multiprocessing`.

But I'm hoping it could be solved using `*argv` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So this works:

```
def get_attributes(doc):
    with ThreadPool(2) as p:
        results = p.map(lambda x: doc[x], ["id", "created_utc", "title", "subreddit"])
        return results

# Map each document to the attribute function
def get_data(docs):
    with ThreadPool(2) as pool:
        results = pool.map(get_attributes, docs)
        return results
```

But only with `ThreadPool`, using `Pool` gave me a pickle error. I'm plenty happy with the result but if anyone can offer tips to further optimize, or explain what a pickle is and why I had to use `ThreadPool` vs. `Pool`, I'd be very happy to hear it!

Comment: You can't use `Pool` because it creates separate processes that run in their own memory-space — which means no shared global resources (unlike with threads). When you pass an argument to these external processes, as you're doing, an attempt is made to pickle the data before transmitting it. The pickle module handles many but not all data-types, and it looks like `docs` is one of the ones it cannot.

Comment: Thank you @martineau

Comment: @martineau, would ```lru_cache``` have any effect on the memory accessible to the processes?

Comment: `lru_cache` is for something else completely and not affect the accessibility. You might be able to make `docs` pickable, what ever it is.